# JFrame Restricted due to restriction on required library

Tags: java, swing

I am making a new Java project in eclipse. The only problem is that I didn't even get five lines in before I got an error that reads:

```
Access Restriction: The type JFrame is not accessible due to restriction on 
required library C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\rt.jar
```

How do I fix this issue? Please forgive me if someone already asked a similar question. I am still a beginner.

Answer (score 36):

Try removing and readding the Java System Library to your project:

Project Properties -> Build Path -> Libraries -> Remove , and then Add Library -> JRE System Library

Try closing and reopening the Dialog after removing the the Library

Comment: Why does this work? More importantly, why does this happen? +1

Comment: @Nick if it still matters,it's because the original path of the JRE is changed and the project JRE path doesn't match the actual path.