# Implementing swing in jdk 1.8 using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, java-8

I was trying to implement the concept of  swing using `eclipse` in `jdk 1.8` but when I used the identifier like `JButton` then an error came :

```
The type JButton is not accessible due to restriction on required library C:\ProgramFiles
\Java\jre 1.8.0_31\lib\rt.jar
```

I am a newbie Java programmer.Can someone please help me out with this error?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I don't quite understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266632/access-restriction-is-not-accessible-due-to-restriction-on-required-library

Comment: I was trying to make a GUI using the concept of swing but when I used the keywords like "JButton" and "JPanel" then it was showing me the above error.

Comment: @ram can you post a snapshot ??

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not have enough reputation to post image.

Comment: @ram but you can post image somewhere and link here.upload your image to http://imgur.com/ and give the link.because question is unclear to me sry

Comment: @FastSnail : i have uploaded the image ,here's the link:   http://imgur.com/uZJd9as

Comment: @ram good but you can use snippy tool to take a quality snapshot without camera

Comment: related  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600077/jframe-restricted-due-to-restriction-on-required-library  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600077/jframe-restricted-due-to-restriction-on-required-library

Comment: @FastSnail : thanks a lot .the errors have been fixed.

Comment: `JButton` is not a keyword. Keywords are the 50 words [listed here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9). `JButton` is an identifier and in the context you want to use it, most probably, it’s a class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project settings are wrong. An ancient question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar) with the same issue (and the correct way to resolve it).

Basically you need to check your project's `Build Path` to make sure that it's referring to the default `JRE` and you're not including the Swing classes from somewhere else causing a conflict: Eclipse sees that you're trying to use class `JButton` from `foobar.jar` instead of `rt.jar` and is saying that it's not right.