# Jython Importing Problems in Eclipse

Tags: java, python, eclipse, jython

Have a quick question, I started using Jython a while ago and I tried following the book to learn about it, but when it came to importing things like JButton or JFrame, I get "unresolved import" error on them. I made sure that Jython is correctly installed and has a Jython_Home path, has the correct interpreter, and is included in the systems path alongside python. Let me know if there's any other info needed, I'll gladly provide it. I really want to find out why it's not working out. Thanks much!

Quick Edit: When importing to command-line, it works. so like

from javax.swing import JButton, JFrame

and I'm able to create a frame and button, but when putting it on Eclipse, it does the "unresolved import"

Here are two screenshots of Eclipse

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_9Pnwvp6_sbSKQXiLShUnrnpMrwqFOqb

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1asH5YokYcx1lBMzceOiRCIj5_ubnbk1a/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Works fine here. What **exactly** does your import look like?

Comment: post a snippet, and how is your lib setup in eclipse looking?

Comment: Here are two links to screenshots of eclipse

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_9Pnwvp6_sbSKQXiLShUnrnpMrwqFOqb/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1asH5YokYcx1lBMzceOiRCIj5_ubnbk1a/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Probably you can find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30748998/implementing-swing-in-jdk-1-8-using-eclipse?lq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Doesn't work, I get "No Actions Available" for the build path